# Unexpected Token with Scripts using Jade and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am new to Jade and I am having some problems with the Scripts.

In some of them, I get Unexpected Token errors... this is one example:

```
script
    $(document).ready({

        $('#answer').keyup(function(e) {
            $('#preview').html($('#answer').val());
        });

    });
```

This should work fine in common HTML, but with Jade it says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Do I have to use any special syntax with Jade?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the error is in this piece of code?

Comment: @TJ- Yes, it's in that piece. It also gives me an error in another page when I put this:
script(type="text/x-mathjax-config")
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
   inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
   skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre","code"] 
   }
  
 });
(Sorry but the new lines are not shown here)

Comment: I added that to one of my views and didn't get an error. Are you using the latest version of jade?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Can you check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535621/integration-of-mathjax-and-jadejs please?
I figured out this one but I can't with the Mathjax piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

In jade, script should be followed by .(dot)

like => script. (or) script(type="text/javascript").